# Argue, using symmetry, that the average distance between two points on a unit circle must exceed 1

Tags: calculus, average

**Textbook problem:**

> Two points are chosen at random on the circumference of a circle of radius $1$. Let $D$ be the average distance between them. Argue, using principles of symmetry, that $D$ must exceed $1$.

**Textbook solution:**

> Suppose the first point chosen is at the north pole of the circle. I assert that the average *vertical* distance to the second point will be exactly $1$. Indeed, the possible second points can be paired up: a point at distance $h$ below the north pole paired up with a corresponding point at distance $h$ above the south pole, and **the average vertical distance of these two points from the north pole is $1$**. Since the average distance between the points must exceed the vertical distance, it must exceed $1$.

**Question:** Why is it valid to average the vertical distance of these two points to get the average vertical distance of any two points (the step in bold above)?  I understand the rest of the argument, but this step I do not see exactly why it holds.

To get the average vertical distance of these two points for this step I did the following:

- North pole point has coordinates $(0,1)$
- Second chosen point (in the first or second quadrant) on the circle has coordinates $(x,1-h)$ for some $x$
- The paired-up corresponding point above the south pole has coordinates $(x,h-1)$
- From the north pole, averaging the vertical distance of the two points is then $\frac{1-(1-h)+1-(h-1)}{2} = 1$ since $1-(1-h)$ is the vertical distance from the north pole to one point and $1-(h-1)$ is the vertical distance from the north pole to the other point

[image]

Note that I'm able to use the integral definition of average value of a function to find that the exact answer is $4/\pi$.

Comment: I would have expected the symmetry argument to be "the average distance from the north pole must be the same as the average distance to the south pole (proof: flip the circle over about its equator). Therefore it is 1"

Comment: @eyeballfrog That reminds me more of the concept of a median than an average because it sounds like it relies on something like half the time the point is here and half the time is there where the equator is the median or something.

Comment: @UngarLinski  Each point vertical distance from North Pole is $2 - $ (vert. list. from South Pole). So if the ave. vert. dist. from North Pole is $A$, then ave. vert. dist. from South P. is $2 - A$ (by linearity of expectation). But by symmetry these two averages are equal ...

Comment: @Ned Can you expand on this and show where or how you used linearity?

Comment: @UngarLinski If $X$ (resp. $Y$) is the vert. distance of a point from the North (resp. South) Pole, then $Y = 2-X$. So, by linearity of expectation $E(Y) = E(2-X) = E(2) - E(X) = 2 - E(X)$. By symmetry $E(Y)=E(X)$ so $E(X) = 2 - E(X)$ and thus $E(X) = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid proof because of the nature of right triangles.

Whichever point is chosen first, we can rotate the circle to make that the north pole. Since the distance to the south pole is two, the average vertical distance, as pointed out in the proof, is one. But the distance to any of the other points on the circle is the hypotenuse of a triangle with one leg equal to the vertical distance. Since the hypotenuse of the triangle is larger than any of its two legs, the average distance must be greater than the average vertical distance. Since the average vertical distance is one, the average distance must be greater than one.

EDIT: Through the discussion in the comments, Ungar's real difficulty was understanding why the average vertical distance is $1$. At his request, I paste the following comment from below into this answer.

We are trying to show that the average distance from the north pole to the south pole is $1$. Forget the circle and concentrate on the interval between $0$ and $2$. There is one point that is a distance of one away. For every other point, e.g. $\frac{1}{4}$, there is a point $\frac{7}{4}$. Their average is 1. For $\frac{1}{10}$, there is $\frac{19}{10}$ and their average is $1$. That's why the average is $1$. Every point that is not a distance of $1$ away is paired with a point whose distance is such that the average is $1$.

Comment: The triangle and hypotenuse part of the argument I get.  It's the part I put in boldface that I don't think I follow.  Your explanation above does not use the author's paired-up points along with the point at the north pole.  See what I mean?

Comment: @UngarLinski The part in boldface is the part where the average vertical distance is one, right? The average of a set of points is the place where you would place a fulcrum to balance them. If you have an interval $[a,b]$, the average is $\frac{a+b}{2}$. Is that your difficulty? The author is trying to prove that by saying every distance above the horizontal diameter is as equally likely as every distance below.

Comment: But then why does he use three points in making his argument?  Half the points on one side and half on the other is the median which is not always the average.  I think that's why he's using the vertical distance from the north pole to two separate points.  I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: So it seems like he's saying take the vertical distance from the north pole to two separate points, and then average these which gives you $1$.  But I am not clear if that is what he means.

Comment: @UngarLinski No. Those points come in pairs. In other words, consider any vertical distance from the north pole. For any point at a fixed distance, there is a point at the same distance to the opposite side of the horizontal diameter with equal probability of being selected. Thus, the average is the distance to the horizontal diameter. It is also a median but it is the average.

Comment: @UngarLinski We are trying to show that the average distance from the north pole to the south pole is $1$. Forget the circle and concentrate on the interval between $0$ and $2$. There is one point that is a distance of one away. For every other point, e.g. $\frac{1}{4}$, there is a point $\frac{7}{4}$. Their average is $1$. For $\frac{1}{10}$, there is $\frac{19}{10}$ and their average is $1$. That's why the average is $1$. Every point that is not a distance of $1$ away is paired with a point whose distance is such that the average is $1$.

Comment: That's it!  I was pairing them wrong.  That answers my question exactly.  I misinterpreted the part I boldfaced as saying to average the vertical distance from the north pole to point 1 with the vertical distance from the north pole to point 2.  This, coincidentally, also gives you $1$ but I could not wrap my head around why we would average two vertical distances like that.

Comment: Can you edit your comment into your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @UngarLinski Done.

Comment: _"We are trying to show that the average distance from the north pole to the south pole is 1"_ - no, the average distance from one pole to the other is $2$. I believe this was a typo.

Comment: @paperskilltrees There s no typo. The distance to the south pole is $2$ so the average distance of all the points from the north pole to the south pole is $1$. I suppose you could be literal and say that there is only one point at the south pole and its distance is $2$ so, therefore, the average distance is $2$ but that would be ignoring the context of the conversation and a little pedantic.

Comment: @paperskilltrees Also, we were talking about the vertical distance. That was the part of the original proof that Ungar didn't understand.